# How to get the commit history for a specific developer in Magit?

Tags: magit

Using the command <kbd>ll</kbd> in magit would get the complete commit history, but how can one show only the commits by an individual developer?

I checked the cheetsheet but can't find a valid solution.

Comment: After `l` (for logging) did you try pressing `=a` (limit to author option)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at the arguments available in the logging popup (<kbd>l</kbd>). One of them is `--author`, described as "Limit to author". Sounds like that's what you want.

Are you talking about the cheatsheet by Daemian Mack? If so then have a look at the top of that page and notice that it sais "THIS CHEATSHEET IS OBSOLETE AS OF MAGIT V2". Below that you will also find links to more up-to-date documentation.